# Xss when I save html document

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, xss

When entering

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

The resulting Html after submitting is

```
<form action="/action_page.php"  novalidate>
  E-mail: <input type="email"  Id="user_email">"<script>alert(1)</script>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the xss not triggered.
If I replace the payload with

```
<img src=xss onerror=alert(1)>
```

Xss triggered! 
this xss happening with the id attribute! 
In browsers.

So I want to know 2 thing.

1. If this is a vulnerability then how an attacker can use it. I mean what payload would be used. Cause xss happening with `Id=` attribute
2. If this is a vulnerability. How can I fix it?

I am a beginner. I will be happy if you guys answer my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

> 1. If this is a vulnerability then how an attacker can use it. I mean what payload would be used. Cause xss happening with Id= attribute

It doesn't matter *where* the XSS happens, what matters is that an attacker is able to execute arbitrary javascript. XSS with a `<script>` tag is identical in impact with an XSS within an HTML attribute. In either case, the attacker can do things like:

- load an external script that logs all key presses on the page
- modify the look/behavior of the page to capture credentials
- make requests as the authenticated user
- send secret values in cookies to an attacker
- and pretty much anything you can think to do with javascript

If you want a simple example, you can just take your payload you have that launches an alert, and replace it with something like you'd find here: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) . I think it's asking too much to come up with a working exploit for a page we can't test against, but you should get the idea.

> 2. If this is a vulnerability. How can I fix it?

It sure sounds like a stored XSS vulnerability to me. There are many sources for preventing XSS in PHP. You can check out some of these Q&As:

- [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19524/current-best-practices-to-prevent-persistent-xss-attacks

I would also recommend you read this page: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

And finally, if possible, have someone with more security expertise review your code.

Comment: Very informative! Thank You so much!